# LLVM insert opcode before instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to insert specific opcode before BasicBlock terminator, in my case before ReturnInst.

It is possible?

Example:

> ```
> TerminatorInst* terminator = BasicBlock->getTerminator();
> if (isa<ReturnInst>(terminator))  
> {
> //Insert opcode here.    
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by using **llvm::InlineAsm**

```
llvm::InlineAsm *AsmCode = llvm::InlineAsm::get(Asm, nopInstruction, "", true, false, llvm::InlineAsm::AD_Intel);
```

where Asm - llvm::FunctionType, nopInstruction - llvm::StringRef(char*)

Answer (score 1):

By "opcode" I guess you mean "instruction".

All instructions have a constructor which receives another instruction as its last parameter; that constructor creates the new instruction and then inserts it right before the instruction that was given as the last argument, precisely what you're looking for.

For more information about this, see the ["creating and inserting new instruction" section of the user guide](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#creating-and-inserting-new-instructions).

Comment: Thank you! How i can add instruction which does not present in LLVM (Instructions.h)?

Comment: @Denis can you give an example of what you want to insert?

Comment: Simple, i want to insert nop(0x90) instruction before ret

Comment: @Denis 0x90 is the nop instruction in *x86 binaries*, not in LLVM IR - those are two different, distinct languages (though [you can embed assembly inside LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#inline-assembler-expressions)). You can check out the list of all LLVM IR instructions in [the LLVM Language Reference manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) - in particular, there's no nop instruction there.

Comment: Yes i know, any hack for this?

Comment: @Denis I can't imagine any reason why anyone would want to do that... but as I wrote above, it *is* possible by using the existing mechanism of embedding inline asm code, check out the link I provided in the langref manual.

Comment: Thanks! if i compare two integers, ICmpInst *test = new ICmpInst(terminator, CmpInst::ICMP_EQ, const_int32_1, const_int32_2,"check"); Instruction get removed after asm code generated (llc name.ll), i need to create branch for this?

Comment: @Denis I have a hard time imagining your code here... I suggest you open a new question about it, with fuller code snippets.